# Swift: Not able to navigate to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

[image]

I really do not know what mistake am I doing in the following lines:

```
// Instantiate SecondViewController
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegistrationScreen2View") as! RegistrationScreen2ViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

I am not able to move to second view controller in the story board I have mentioned  story board id as `RegistrationScreen2View` for `RegistrationScreen2ViewController.`

I am getting the following exception:

```
2016-10-24 11:26:16.607 toadways[965:11142] -[toadways.RegistrationScreen1ViewController continue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe05dc34ec0
2016-10-24 11:26:16.619 toadways[965:11142] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[toadways.RegistrationScreen1ViewController continue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe05dc34ec0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010efa534b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ea0621e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f014f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef2ac15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef2a798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010f3cab88 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010f5502b2 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010f5505cb -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010f54f4c7 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010f4380d5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010f4397c3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010f3e6a33 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010fbd8b6d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010fbd1817 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef4a311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef2f59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef2ea86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef2e494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000116c0ca6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010f3c8f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  toadways                            0x000000010e2318bf main + 111
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011266368d start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Please let me know what mistake am I doing.

Comment: Check your implementation of [toadways.RegistrationScreen1ViewController continue], I suspect it’s missing implementation.

Comment: did you use button action for push ?

Comment: @Vakas I didn't understand. Missing implementation means?

Comment: @KKRocks I have created IBAction for button and then I am using it.

Comment: ok then check action connection in storyboard.

Comment: The exception says that a method/function called `continue` was called on an instance of `RegistrationScreen1ViewController`, but that class does not have that method/function.

Comment: @KKRocks connections are proper.

Comment: @Paulw11 function continue is called on an instance of Continue Button and not RegistrationScreen1ViewController.

Comment: @focus,  I don't know what you *think* you are doing, but what you *are* doing is calling `continue` on an instance of `RegistrationScreen1ViewController` - the exception says so.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have updated the question with an image of outlet and actions of RegistrationViewController, please have a look and advice

Comment: Nothing in that image shows a function/property `continue` so the problem is somewhere else.  Does the crash occur as soon as you trigger the segue to the next screen?  What is the trigger for the code you have shown in your question?

Comment: @Paulw11   Yes, the code posted in the question triggers the crash. There are few validations of other outlets, I have debugged the code the app crashes when I come to this part of the code in the function.

Comment: How do you trigger that code?  Is it in an `@IBAction`?  I take it that `RegistrationScreen1ViewController` is the *current* ViewController?  You have something in your storyboard that is calling a function called `continue` - Search through your app for `continue` - there will be a reference in your storyboard.  By the way, there is no need for any code to do what you want.  You can have a direct segue from the action of the button to the next scene

Comment: @Paulw11 I want to perform few validations when I click the button, which function is called when I click that button when I add a segue

Comment: You can implement `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` to perform validation

Comment: @Paulw11 ok will check this

Comment: @Paulw11 I added segue instead of IBAction and removed the action from both story board and code. But still I am getting the same error, what might be causing this issue?

Comment: You need to look for that method invocation somewhere in your project. Use the project search or if you can, upload your project or perhaps just your storyboard somewhere

Comment: @Paulw11 cleaned the code and tried, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your code should work. The most possibility is that you forgot to input an Storyboard ID for your destination ViewController.

***How to Fix:

In the Identity Inspector of destination ViewController, enter its ID.

[image]